# How to set image in same height using bootstrap?

Tags: css, angular-ui-bootstrap

[image]I was trying to put same size of image for all card but some images has already small height then How can I fix that?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="card h-100" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="/assets/prewedding/pic1.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="card h-100" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="/assets/prewedding/pic2.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set the `img` to cover the container, like

```
.card > img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```